# The wait.until returns stale element, how to wait until DOM is stable

Tags: c#, selenium, blazor

I have a blazor application running fine and want to have some behavior test with selenium. The test does now currently the following:

- goes to a page (directly using an URL, no page loaded before)
- tries to click on a button

The first point does work, but the second has an issue. If I use the `wait.until` the button is available, then I receive back an early version of the button, which then redrawn and updated in the DOM later. This will give me the "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document" error.

Here is the code:

```
var xPath = By.XPath($".//tr//td[normalize-space()=\"{name}\"]/ancestor-or-self::tr//button");
var button = _wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(xPath));
Thread.Sleep(1000);
button = _chromeDriver.FindElement(xPath);
button.Click();
```

the `_wait.until` will return an item that will be stale, while the next `FindElement` will return a valid, but only after ~1 sec sleep. If I don't have sleep there, it will return the same as the other line.

The final question: How can I ensure in the `_wait.until` line, that my returned element is the final one to avoid using `Thread.Sleep`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no gentle solution for such issues.
The only solution I know for this is to make a loop:
Wait for element clickability and click it.
In case exception is thrown wait for the clickability again.
If click succed - break the loop and continue to outer code / return `True`.
Something like this:

```cs
for(i=0; i<6; i++){
    try: {
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(xPath)).Click(); 
        break;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically you need to do this. Attempt some operation until it succeeds.

Comment: I typically create an extension method for WebDriverWait that accepts a `void` return type, so I can write code like: `wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(By.XPath("...")).Click());` This saves you from writing a loop every place.

Comment: @GregBurghardt to say the truth I didn't work with sates having `StaleElement` issues almost ever :) My experience with it mostly from resolving problems here, on SO :)

Comment: This is more of a workaround for me.

Comment: What do you mean? English is not my mother tongue, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium Wait.Until conditions are not 100% reliable. I was in shock when I figureג this myself, but yes, after the condition has finished you sometimes have to wait or try clicking or hovering in a loop.

I wish to suggest 2 options here:

1. Wait for the element to be both Clickable and Enabled:

   getWait().until((ExpectedCondition) driver -> element.isEnabled());
2. Use a much better UI tool for testing like `Playwright`. It has a much sophisticated waiting system conditions and is also faster and very reliable.

Comment: What's written here is a proof of not reading Selenium documentation. Just this sentence in point 1 shows you might not be aware what waitForElementClickable does: "An expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.". What you're missing here is waiting for a presence in DOM, which only can be checked on By object level..

Answer (score 1):

@golddragon007, you can wait for the element to become stale.

```
_wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(_chromeDriver.FindElement(xPath)))
```

you can check the following link for more details:

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_StalenessOf.htm

Answer (score 0):

[Prophet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73803163/3092298) is a good approach, so have a look at that. Sometimes you just need to try something more than one time. This is an alternative that is easier to reuse and more flexible.

All of the methods on the WebDriverWait class expect a lambda express to return a value. Sometimes I need to call a method with a `void` return type, so I write an extension method on WebDriverWait to support this:

```
public static class WebDriverWaitExtensions
{
    public static void Until(this WebDriverWait wait, Action<IWebDriver> action)
    {
        wait.Until(driver =>
        {
            action(driver);

            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

This is much more flexible and easier to call with your code. This will attempt to click the element until it succeeds. A word of caution, however. The `StaleElementException` will cancel a wait operation immediately. Be sure to ignore this kind of exception.

```
var xPath = By.XPath($".//tr//td[normalize-space()=\"{name}\"]/ancestor-or-self::tr//button");

_wait.IgnoredExceptionTypes(typeof(StaleElementException));

_wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(xpath).Click());
```

This should work with any web driver method that has a `void` return type.

Answer (score 0):

It seems another solution is this:

```
_wait.Until(driver => (bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return typeof Blazor.reconnect != 'undefined'"));
```

as that variable only loaded when the page is fully loaded. And after that it's possible to do a simple find without an issue:

```
var button = _chromeDriver.FindElement(xPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement polly as your resilience framework for Selenium methods you create an example you can see below:

```
public static IWebElement Click(string xPath, int retries = 15,
    int retryInterval = 1)
{
    var element = Policy.HandleResult<IWebElement>(result => result == null)
        .WaitAndRetry(retries, interval => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryInterval))
        .Execute(() =>
        {
            var element = Searchers.FindWebElementByXPath(xPath);
            if (element != null)
            {
                _logger.Info("Clicked Element: " + xPath + " (" + element.Text + ")");

                try
                {
                    _driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
                    return element;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (e is ElementClickInterceptedException or StaleElementReferenceException)
                        return null;
                }
            }

            return null;
        });


    if (element != null) return element;

    _logger.Info("Failed to click Element: " + xPath + "");
    throw new Exception(" Failed to use Javascript to click element with XPath: " + xPath + "");
}
```

By leveraging the power of polly, I can guarantee that all of my events will go through.

Do not use the base Selenium methods to wait for certain properties to change/be a certain value, they are not very reliable.